# ogr2ogr - Convert geojson to shapefile create offset in coordinates

Tags: shapefile, geojson, ogr2ogr

I want to convert this geojson file below into a shapefile using ogr2ogr command `ogr2ogr output.shp input.geojson`.

However, an offset is appearing in the output coordinates that make the shapefile not correctly aligned with the input.

input.geojson:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[[-7551132, 6293816],[-7560916, 6260489]],
         },
         "properties":{
            "id":36
         }
      }
   ],
   "crs":{
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:3857"
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a problem with my geojson? What could be the cause of the offset?

Comment: How do you observe the offset?

Comment: In QGIS - but I have found the origin of the problem see edit soon

Comment: GeoJSON specification is here http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html. `The crs member should be on the top-level GeoJSON object in a hierarchy (in feature collection, feature, geometry order) and should not be repeated or overridden on children or grandchildren of the object.` I can't say really if first GeoJSON is invalid. Does missing crs on feature collection level mean that it is the default CRS84 and it must not be overridden later?

Comment: A new test by moving crs from Feature collection into Feature made no difference for GDAL. It stil interprets that data are in EPSG:3857.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a shapefile from your linestring

```
ogrinfo line.shp -al
INFO: Open of `line.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: line
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-7560916.000000, 6260489.000000) - (-7551132.000000, 6293816.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
OGRFeature(line):0
  LINESTRING (-7551132 6293816,-7560916 6260489)
```

Next I converted it into GeoJSON

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -a_srs epsg:3857 line.json line.shp
```

I can't find any difference with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo -ro -al line.json
INFO: Open of `line.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: OGRGeoJSON
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-7560916.000000, 6260489.000000) - (-7551132.000000, 6293816.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +
x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
OGRFeature(OGRGeoJSON):0
  LINESTRING (-7551132 6293816,-7560916 6260489)
```

For verification convert the GeoJSON back to shape:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" roundtrip.shp line.json
```

What we got:

```
ogrinfo -al roundtrip.shp
INFO: Open of `roundtrip.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: roundtrip
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-7560916.000000, 6260489.000000) - (-7551132.000000, 6293816.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["WGS_84_Pseudo_Mercator",
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0.0]]
FID: Integer64 (11.0)
OGRFeature(roundtrip):0
  FID (Integer64) = 0
  LINESTRING (-7551132 6293816,-7560916 6260489)
```

Coordinates seem to be identical with the original ones.

Conclusion: Use low level tools for debugging. You can never know what a big program like QGIS is doing on the background.

Comment: the problem is converting geojson to shapefile, not shapefile to geojson

Comment: Ok, I continued with going back from GeoJSON into shapefile. Looks still OK.

Comment: Thank you for the verification. I think my problem is completely elsewhere

Comment: I edited the GeoJSON that was created by GDAL and moved the crs to features. Ogrinfo reports the crs as EPSG:3857 and a new roundtrip to shapefile gives the same result as earlier.